# Ansible conditional with variable

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements

I have to build a cluster where certain packages should be installed on all hosts while other packages are installed on specific hosts only.

I wish to add a conditional to my yum install loop to select the target host based on my inventory groups (master, slave, all).

```
- name: Install Package
  when: inventory_hostname in groups[ {{item.host }} ]
  yum:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
  loop:
    - {name: 'package_1', host: 'master'}
    - {name: 'package_2', host: 'slave'}
    - {name: 'package_3', host: 'all'}
```

I understand that jinja2 templating is not an option, but I couldn't find what is the right way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about having (3) plays targeted to each group and installing the appropriate package?

Comment: How about [organizing hosts and groups with variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)?

Comment: @seshadri_c - Yes, I've considered that option, however, we talk about a single cluster with four VMs. Most of the packages will be installed on all machines. With separate plays I should repeate a good portion of my code, which in my opinion would add unneccessary complexity. However, I'm on the beginning of my Ansible journey, so I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the warning. Conditionals like `when` are already a Jinja expression, so you should not use additional Jinja delimiters within them. This does not mean you cannot use variables, it means you don't need to do anything special to access them.

```
  when: inventory_hostname in groups[item.host]
```

Comment: Much appreciate it! Worked like a charm!